# Random reboots after installing Nvidia driver for RTX 4090

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, gpu-driver

I have Ubuntu 20.04.06 LTS installed with the kernel 5.15.0-76-generic. I tried installing the appropriate Nvidia Drivers for my 4090, either the 525.125.06 or the 535.54.03 driver, but the system began to reboot randomly. I am not playing any games, just going online and downloading other apps like Chrome.

The reboots only started once the Nvidia driver was installed. I’ve tried installing the drivers using the “Additional Drivers” method, the sudo apt install Nvidia-driver-XXX command and running the appropriate .run file from Nvidia. The nvidia-bug-report.log file is attached here: https://justpaste.it/afn8v

I have the following for my PC: Intel Core i7-13700F, MSI MAG B760 Tomahawk DDR4, Silverstone HELA 1200R Platinum 1200W ATX 3.0. Thank you.

Comment: Look at the logs just before the last reboot with `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` use `sudo journalctl  --list-boots` to see other values for `-b`. If the logs (of several "random reboots") don't show a pattern, it's probably insufficient power or overheating.

Comment: Try Ubuntu 22.04 or 23.04 with later kernels for your 4090.